# ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jpa, tomcat

I have been trying to deploy my spring boot WAR file into a separated tomcat local server.
Unfortunately while its working in embedded tomcat in independent tomcat I confront with

**has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer]**) error

whole of my dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.inteligent</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
         <version>6.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>

         <!-- Configure the Tomcat Maven plugin -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <url>http://localhost:8088/manager/text</url>
               <path>/rps</path>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>


         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>19</source>
               <target>19</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

also I changed project structure in InteliJ Idea as below

[Project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIzkC.png)

[SDK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqQ9p.png)

[Modules settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk92U.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDF2j.png)

but nothing has been changed

Comment: Use the same version of java in your sources as tomcat use.

Comment: how can I change that? java home is pointing to java 19

Comment: You are targeting java 17. Tomcat runs with an older Java